# How to read data in file which the file inside a file in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have list2.txt file and inside that file, there are several files like `02x5.txt` or `0.3x5.txt` etc. Then how to read data inside `02x5.txt` file at one time? Inside `02x5.txt`, there are `height:20, length:5, colour:blue` etc.

```
inside list2.txt:
02x5.txt
03x5.txt


inside 02x5.txt:
height:20, 
length:5, 
colour:blue

inside 03x5.txt:
height:25, 
length:10, 
colour:green
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

# Reading a line from a file (or rather from a filehandle)
my $filename = "list2.txt";
    if (open my $data, "<", $filename) {
    while (my $row = <$data>) {
        chomp $row;
        if ($row =~ m/02x5.txt$/ ){
        my $m = $row;
            print "$m\n";
        }
    }
    }
```

How can I read data for height and length from certain txt file?
Thank you

Comment: Is list2.txt really a text file?

Comment: yes , There are a bunch of txt file inside list2.txt.

Comment: Or, does list2.txt contain the names of the text files and not actually the files themselves?

Comment: Why chomp and then print an extra newline?  Just leave the newline in `$row`.  It won't affect the match.

Comment: @Notamachine yes.. list.txt contain the names of txt file

Comment: @WilliamPursell ok thanks. i will remove chomp.

Comment: Once you identify a filename in your `list2.txt` then you need to open that file as well (with its own filehandle) so that you can read from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is always to break the problem down into smaller chunks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = get_list_of_files();

my %data;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  my $file_data = get_data_from_file($file);

  $data{$file} = $file_data;
}

# You now have your data in a hash called %data.
# Do whatever you want with it.

sub get_list_of_files {
  open my $list_fh, '<', 'list2.txt'
    or die $!;

  my @files = <$list_fh>;
  chomp(@files);

  return @files;
}

sub get_data_from_file {
  my ($filename) = @_;

  my $record;

  open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;

  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    # Remove trailing comma
    s/,$//;
    my ($key, $value) = split /:/;
    $record->{$key} = $value;
  }

  return $record;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see following piece of code which performs tasks you've described, read data stored in hash `%data` which you can use anyway you desire.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;

my $filename = 'list2.txt';

my %data;

open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename";

my @filenames = <$fh>;

close $fh;

chomp @filenames;

foreach $filename(@filenames) {
    open $fh, '<', $filename
        or die "Couldn't open $filename";

    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        my($k,$v) = split ':';
        $data{$filename}{$k} = $v;
    }

    close $fh;
}

say Dumper(\%data);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '02x5.txt' => {
                          'colour' => 'blue',
                          'height' => '20, ',
                          'length' => '5, '
                        },
          '03x5.txt' => {
                          'length' => '10, ',
                          'colour' => 'green',
                          'height' => '25, '
                        }
        };
```